# Passing by ref a parameter to macro calling a excel DNA function with Application.Run

Tags: c#, vba, reference, excel-dna

I have a `c#` function defined through excel DNA :

```
[ExcelFunction(Description = "does stuff", IsVolatile = false, IsMacroType = true, IsThreadSafe = true)]
public object AFunction(long k \* other parameters *\)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

that is called in VBA as follows :

```
Dim v As Variant
v = Application.Run("AFunction", k)
```

Now I modify my excel DNA `c#` as follows :

```
[ExcelFunction(Description = "Retrieves valo folio", IsVolatile = false, IsMacroType = true, IsThreadSafe = true)]
public object AFunction(ref double x, long k \* other parameters *\)
{
    // do stuff
    // update x
}
```

the idea being that I will pass to it a `double` that will be updated, and that I will use after.

I call this in VBA as follows :

```
Dim v As Variant
v = Application.Run("AFunction", x, k)
```

But `x` ("dimed" `as Double`) is not updated. I tried a

```
Dim x() as Double
Redim x(1)
```

and a

```
Dim v As Variant
v = Application.Run("AFunction", x(1), k)
```

but here also `x(1)` is not updated.

Is there a problem with the `ref` in the `c#`, or is the problem caused by the `Application.Run` ?

Comment: `Application.Run` does not support byref parameters by design. It wraps passed values into variants and passes them forward.

Comment: You can put this in an answer so that I'll accept. Thx anyway.

Comment: On contrary, `CallByName` supports `byref`. Is there a class you can call `CallByName` on?

Comment: No, `AFunction` is a `c#` Excel DNA function that produces an Excel UDF `AFunction` callable primarily from Excel, that I call from VBA (personal convenience) using `Application.Run`. Are you saying I can use `CallByName` in my context ?

Comment: Yes, if you had a class that exposes the function as its member. E.g. Excel built in functions are members of `WorksheetFunction` class and can be called with `CallByName` (they don't have byref parameters but it would work if they did). I'm not familiar with Excel DNA, but if there is also a parent class somewhere it could work.

Comment: Apparently this also works with `Application.Run`, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `Application.Run` indeed, as suspected, because it can't *a priori* pass parameters by reference. But in fact it can, see here :

http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1022_ByRef_Argument_with_the_Application_Run_method.shtml

where basically one wraps the UDF in a method of a VBA class of which an instance is passed using `Application.Run`

Cumbersome but working.