# How to retrieve Variant array from VBA in C#?

Tags: c#, vba, com, interop, variant

I call a function in VBA, from which I want to retrieve an array of strings. For that I declared a function with ByRef parameter of type Variant:

```
Public Function TestErrorsInArray(ByVal path As String, ByRef errors As Variant) As String
    errors = Array("string1", "string2", "string3")
End Function
```

I tested it in VBA with following sub:

```
Public Sub TestTestErrorsInArray()
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array("foo", "bar")
    TestErrorsInArray "", arr
End Sub
```

And it works OK - arr values are changed to those from errors list.

In C# I call it like this:

```
object errors = null;
var test = WordTools.GetWordApplication().Run("TestErrorsInArray", "", errors);
```

Unfortunatelly, it seems that errors variable doesn't change at all... It stays as null. If I initiate it as empty array, it stays as empty array etc.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44000002/3219613 `.Run` cannot pass parameters by reference I think.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same issue. First of all, in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word you can see declaration of Run method with 'ref' keywords: `dynamic Run(System.String MacroName, ref System.Object varg1, ref System.Object varg2, ref System.Object varg3...` Second thing is that I can pass strings and ints ByRef with no problem...

Comment: The fact there is a 'ref' doesn't mean anything you can pass can be modified "inplace", it just means the object is passed by reference. When working across processes/threads, the referenced value is just copied one way (in this case). You can use an intermediary class to do the trick: http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1022_ByRef_Argument_with_the_Application_Run_method.shtml